# how can I display tabular data in a flex-box?

Tags: vue.js, flexbox

How can I display tabular data in a flexbox? It us vuejs but I hope my question is generic. Maybe could I just simply drop the table and create divs to style it?

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>date</th>
          <th>image</th>
          <th>title</th>
          <th>press</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody >
        <tr v-for="item in items.results" :key="item.id">
          <td>{{ item.pub_date }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.image.file }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.title }}</td>
          <div class="downloads">
            <span
              v-for="downloadable in item.downloadable.filter(d => !!d.document_en)"
              :key="downloadable.id"
             >{{ downloadable.document_en.file }}</span>
           </div>                         
         </tr>
```

**Update:**
What if I simply use a div instead of the tables? How can I organise them into flexboxes?

```
<template>
  <div id="app">  
    <span v-for="item in items.results" :key="item.id">
      {{ item.pub_date }} {{item.image.file}} {{item.title}}
      <div class="downloads">
        <span
          v-for="downloadable in item.downloadable.filter(d => !!d.document_en)"
          :key="downloadable.id"
        >{{ downloadable.document_en.file }}</span>
      </div>
    </span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Please try to specify your question. Add more details, especially about your goal. What exactly do you want to achieve. What's wrong with a table?

Comment: I used the table to get the data sorted from the API but now I would like to use flexboxes to represent the data.

Comment: @BalazsKelemen I Updated the flexbox issue and added demo link. I also created pull request in github. Kindly merge it once you verified the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Step 1:*** Create your `html` template

```
 <ul class="flex-container">
  <li v-for="item in items.results" :key="item.id" class="flex-item">
    <h4>{{ formatDate(item.pub_date) }}, {{item.title}}</h4>
    <img :src="item.image && item.image.file" />
    <div class="downloads">
      <span v-for="downloadable in item.downloadable.filter(d => !!d.document_en)"
        :key="downloadable.id">
        <a :href="downloadable.document_en.file">Download</a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

***Step 2:*** Add your CSS `style` `flex`

```
 <style>
  ul.flex-container {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-direction: row wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  li img {
    display: initial;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .flex-item {
    background: tomato;
    width: calc(100% / 5.5);
    padding: 5px;
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .downloads {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
</style>
```

[image]

[DEMO Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-tree-tuf1b)

Comment: dear Jebasuthan, could I trouble you for a last time: the app worked fine but since I uploaded to github I don`t get the photos and the articles: Please help me: https://github.com/kelbalazs/press-release2

Comment: I don`t need pagination and extra components just simply the flexboxes

Comment: @BalazsKelemen Got it! Will check and let you know.

Comment: I removed the pageload and pagination "feautres" as I just would like to understand how to get those five divs in the flexbox using the unordered list

Comment: @BalazsKelemen Parent ul class `ul.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}` and child `li.flex-item {
  background:aquamarine;
  width: calc(100% / 5.6);
  padding: 5px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color:black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}` using this CSS class you are getting flexboxe design

Comment: @BalazsKelemen You can learn flexbox tricks from here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: that is great, thank you for this, but I still wonder why the pictures and the Explore more article does not show up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238539/discussion-between-jebasuthan-and-balazs-kelemen).